# Using argparse while scheduling array jobs on slurm?

Tags: python, argparse, slurm

I am trying to run an array of jobs using slurm.
I use this command:

```
sbatch --array=0-1 my_script.sh
```

Now, my_script.sh has

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --gres=gpu:1
srun --gres=gpu:1 --chdir=$(pwd) singularity exec --nv --bind /data0 gtc_dev_v9.simg python train.py $1 -v $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID
```

The main part is the way I run the python code. 
Now, train.py expects a list of arguments through command line.

So, to run multiple experiments I define a list of dictionary inside the train.py which has all the argparse paramerters for different experiments I want to run. Now, what I want is to choose a dictionary based on the SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID and ignore the argparse.

The issue right now is that I kept getting argparse error while running this code.

```
train.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -v 1
```

Is there a way to bypass argparse? Because I want keep that option in case required but also be able to choose dictionary. 
Thanks.

Comment: If you put the `parser.parse_args()` call in the `if __name__...` block, it is not run when the module is imported.  It runs and uses `sys.argv` only when called as a script.  You can also call `parser.parse_args(argv)`, where is `argv` is your own list of strings.  If `argv` is `None` it parses `sys.argv[1:]`.

Comment: Yeah. that makes sense. Thanks. I actually defined a dummy variable *v* in argparse to bypass it.